# Считывать новые события из базы postgres

Tags: postgresql

Есть база данных ТКС(таможенная программа). Я могу считать все данные сделать свою арифметику.
И перенести готовые данные в другую базу

Но в базу ТКС(postgres) пришли новые данные

И я хотел бы увидеть что есть новые данные и выгрузить их не могу понять за что зацепится

Спасибо

Comment: [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-notify.html), [Asynchronous Notification](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-notify.html).

Comment: Если думаете про использование listen/notify — обязательно прочтите это: github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_14_STABLE/src/backend/commands/async.c#L16

Comment: Самое важное, что нужно знать про listen/notify это то, что это не гарантированные уведомления. При сбоях БД или приложения они могут теряться. Альтернативы это [чтение журнала транзакций](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) или более специфичное для структуры данных хранение информации в вашей БД о том, что уже обработано, чтобы можно было понять, есть ли изменения в исходной БД.

Comment: Спасибо !!!!!!!!!Незнаю как лайкнуть ответы